# Client Exception Computer vision API

Tags: c#, azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to run the example from this article.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt788620.aspx

I am getting a Client exception. I created the keys here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/my-apis/

In the example, I am passing the api key to the VisionServiceClient. But how do I know which endpoint is my VisionServiceClient pointing? I think there are a few different endpoints depending on the test page

https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fe

how do I Change the endpoint for my VisionServiceClient ?

Comment: Also please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948214/microsoft-cognitive-service-vision-api-clientexception-error/43968837#43968837

Comment: I was just trying to run their example. The version of the package, did not have an argument for the endpoint. Upgraded the package and pointed it to the correct endpoint. Works now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just trying to run their example. The version of the package, did not have an argument for the endpoint. Upgraded the package and pointed it to the correct endpoint. Works now.